# sql oracle new temp column

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL output is like this:

```
column1

50
20
30
```

My final result should be:

```
    column1   column1_temp

#1  50        50%
#2  20        20%
#3  30        30%
```

**What should happen in text:**

```
SQL SUM(column1 #1-#3) = 100 (or what ever comes out as result) which is 
100% |  column1 #1 50 from 100 is 50%
        column1 #2 20 from 100 is 20%
        column1 #3 30 from 100 is 30%
```

Comment: `select column1,  CONCAT(column1,'%') as "column1_copy" from t` ?

Comment: What DB do you use MySQL, SQL or Oracle because you confused me a bit with title of quetion and tags

Comment: its oracle - sorry for confusing you

Comment: Have you tried @danihp 's sql snippet? That should give you what you seem to be needing unless you can provide more information on what you're going for.

Comment: Please check [Calculating percentage of a row over total sum](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/653/calculating-percentage-of-a-row-over-total-sum), assuming that's your question (original edit clearly stated otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select column1,
       (column1 / sum(column1) over ()) * 100 as pct
from the_table
```

You might want to use `to_char()` and/or `round()` to get the formatting you want, but the above should give you the raw numbers.